# Can emmeans be used to predict an outcome using a gam model?

Tags: r, predictive-models, poisson-regression, mgcv, lsmeans

I have run a gam regression on data that looks like the following:

| age | frequency | person_years |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 12796.5 |
| 12 | 2 | 13049.5 |
| 13 | 5 | 13220.0 |
| 14 | 13 | 13313.0 |
| 15 | 27 | 13516.5 |
| 16 | 18 | 13778.5 |

using the following gam function from mgcv

```
incidence.gam <- gam(
  frequency ~ offset(log(person_years)) + s(age),
  data = data,
  family = poisson(link = "log")
)
```

I would like to create a prediction of frequency for all ages using emmeans. I have tried the following

```
emmeans::emmeans(
    incidence.gam,
    ~ age,
    cov.reduce = FALSE,
    type = "response",
    interval = "confidence"
  ) %>% broom::tidy(conf.int = TRUE)
```

however I get the following error and am at a loss how to solve this.

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(tbl, , vars, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
Error in (function (object, at, cov.reduce = mean, cov.keep = get_emm_option("cov.keep"),  : 
  Perhaps a 'data' or 'params' argument is needed
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try what was suggested in the error message?

> Perhaps a 'data' or 'params' argument is needed

```
emmeans::emmeans(
    incidence.gam,
    ~ age,
    cov.reduce = FALSE,
    type = "response",
    data = data
  )
```

... and please note that `interval = "confidence"` has no effect, as that is not an argument for `emmeans()` or `ref_grid()`.